# How to initiate another waterfall dialog after task module submit is triggered? (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

Code for the bot

```
const { DialogSet } = require("botbuilder-dialogs");

const { BaseBot } = require("./basebot");

const { ScheduleDialog } = require("../dialogs/session/schedule-dialog");

class Bot extends BaseBot {
  constructor(conversationState, userState, dialog) {
    super(conversationState, userState, dialog);

    this.scheduleDialog = new ScheduleDialog();

    this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
      const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
      for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; cnt++) {
        if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
          await context.sendActivity("Hi, Welcome to Bot");
        }
      }

      await next();
    });
  }

  async handleTeamsSigninVerifyState(context, state) {
    await this.dialog.run(context, this.dialogState);
  }

  async handleTeamsTaskModuleSubmit(context, taskModuleRequest) {
      await this.scheduleDialog.run(context, this.dialogState);
    }
  }
}

module.exports.Bot = Bot;
```

The `ScheduleDialog` implements the waterfall dialog with 3 steps. When I click submit button in the task module, I am able to get the response in the bot from the first step. But when the control moves to the next step, I am getting the following error:

```
onTurnError] unhandled error: Error: DialogContext.continueDialog(): Can't continue dialog. A dialog with an id of 'ScheduleDialog' wasn't found.
```

Comment: Since you posted this in the samples repo, is there a specific sample you're following? https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/2228

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, I was not able to figure this out, so changed the flow. If you have any solution, I will be happy to know about that.